# JOOQ 3.1 generated filenames are different to the classname causes a compilation error

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Generating off of an oracle db.  There are two functions inside oracle packages that are failing to compile both for naming reasons.  EG there is a pl/sql function get_minutes inside a pkg which gets generated as Getminutes.java but the class name is GetMinutes which gives compiler error:

```
class GetMinutes is public - should be declared in filename GetMinutes.java.
```

Literally the 100's of other functions get generated correctly.
Any ideas why the generation is falling down here?

Comment: What jOOQ version are you using? That sounds like a bug that was fixed around 3-4 years ago...

Comment: Hi its there in the title Jooq 3.1.  It turns out that in all cases it is because there are functions with similar javastyle naming in the pkg.  Eg there are two methods get_minutes and getMinutes.  JooQ generator does not like this and rightly so.

Comment: :) Didn't see the title, somehow. Have you tried upgrading? Although, I think this particular issue won't be solved by upgrading. Will provide an answer soon...

Comment: was able to create the same issue by creating two new tables  - one named TEST_TABLE and another named TESTTABLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ by default translates the common `UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` naming patterns from databases to the more common `PascalCase` class naming patterns in Java. This obviously causes issues when there are naming conflicts between procedures, tables, etc. that have a very similar name.

For this reason jOOQ's code generator ships with generator strategies, which allow you to hook into the code generator whenever a class, constant, reference, member, method, etc. name is generated. There are two ways to configure these strategies:

- **Programmatically**. More powerful, but a bit harder to setup: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy
- **Configuratively**. Less powerful, but very easy to set up: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy

It is relatively easy to configure these strategies to output all names exactly as in the database. jOOQ 3.8 will also have an out-of-the-box strategy for this behaviour (see [#3570](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3570)).